# Image Binding, Silverlight, C#, WP7

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

I have successfully managed to bind images stored in Isolated Storage to "Image" elements inside a listbox defined in XAML w/o any problems.

What I did was to use a property that stored the name and location of the image in isolated storage and an IValueConverter to actually open the file and get its stream.

I am surprised to see that I can't do this in a new XAML with an even easier setup. All I have is this:

```
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <c:BinaryToImageSRCConverter x:Key="imageConverter" />
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Image Name="TheImage" Source="{Binding PhotoName, Converter={StaticResource imageConverter}}" Width="430" Height="430" VerticalAlignment="Center" Stretch="UniformToFill">
        </Image>
    </Grid>
```

and this is what I have in the ModelView:

```
        public string PhotoName { get; set; }
        PhotoName = "Images\\0.jpg";
```

The path and name of the file is correct thus it is not a problem of "not finding the file".

**My problem is that the Convert method of my IValueConverter never gets called.**

As I mentioned before, I am successfully using this converter in another XAML (in the same project) and everything works correctly. The only difference is that I am binding to an image used by a ListBox.

Any ideas or hints as to why the Convert method of my IValueConverter is not called in this scenario ?

Thanks!

Here is what I have tried:

1. Implementing **INotifyPropertyChanged**:

   ```
   public class PhotoNameClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
   public string PhotoNameValue = string.Empty;

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
   {
       if (PropertyChanged != null)
       {
           PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
       }
   }

   public string PhotoName
   {
       get
       {
           return this.PhotoNameValue;
       }
       set
       {
           if (value != this.PhotoNameValue)
           {
               this.PhotoNameValue = value;
               NotifyPropertyChanged("PhotoName");
           }
       }
   }

   }
   ```

This is how I assigned to the property:

```
    public partial class ShowContent : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    PhotoNameClass photoClass = new PhotoNameClass();
}
   protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
      photoClass.PhotoName = "Images\\0.jpg";
      base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }
```

1. **Using DependencyProperty**

   ```
   public partial class ShowContent : PhoneApplicationPage
   ```

   {
       //        PhotoNameClass photoClass = new PhotoNameClass();

   ```
   public string PhotoName
   {
       get { return (string)GetValue(PhotoNameProperty); }
       set { SetValue(PhotoNameProperty, value); }
   }

   public static readonly DependencyProperty PhotoNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("PhotoName", typeof(string), typeof(ShowContent), new PropertyMetadata("")); 

   protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
   {
      PhotoName = "Images\\0.jpg";
   }
   ```

Here are the relevant parts of the XAML:

```
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <c:BinaryToImageSRCConverter x:Key="imageConverter" />
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Image Name="TheImage" Source="{Binding PhotoName, Converter={StaticResource imageConverter}}" Width="430" Height="430" VerticalAlignment="Center" Stretch="UniformToFill">
        </Image>
    </Grid>
```

where, c is defined as:

```
    xmlns:c="clr-namespace:ImageApplication"
```

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I am using the INotifyPropertyChanged implementation to expose my property.

I have changed the XAML code to this:

```
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <c:PhotoNameClass x:Key="photoClass" />
            <c:BinaryToImageSRCConverter x:Key="imageConverter" />
        </Grid.Resources>
            <Image Source="{Binding PhotoName, Converter={StaticResource imageConverter}}" DataContext="{StaticResource photoClass}" Width="430" Height="430" VerticalAlignment="Center" Stretch="UniformToFill">
            </Image>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Therefore, I added the "DataContext" attribute of the image element specifying the name of the class that wraps my property. In this scenario, **the Convert method of the IValueConverter IS called**. However, this is not right as I am getting an error in the XAML when adding DataContext: "Unable to determine application identity of the caller" and of course, stepping into the Convert method, my "value" string is empty therefore, the "right" "PhotoName" is not being populated.

Thanks for any ideas...

P.S. Here's how I defined my Convert method of the IValueConverter:

```
namespace ImageApplication
{
  public class BinaryToImageSRCConverter : IValueConverter
  { 
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    { // <-- Breakpoint here. Never gets triggered except after I added the "DataContext" attribute to the XAML image element.
      // but in that case, "value" is an empty string.
        if (value != null && value is string)
        {
               ...
```

**UPDATE FIXED**

I have fixed the issue. I have assigned the class name wrapping my property to the DataContext property of the image defined in the XAML code.

Thank you all. I hope this will help somebody out there.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you saying that the exact same XAML works fine outside of a ListBox but not inside of one?

Comment: Hi Gabe, I'm saying that I have another XAML inside the same project that uses the same "binding syntax" as the one shown above and everything works ok there. The only difference is that that particular XAML uses the image element inside a listbox.

Comment: provide the converter code also, if you will? there might be something in there that might help

Comment: Blakomen: Hi; I added the Convert's signature just to make sure that it is correct. I didn't add the whole implementation because I don't even get to the FIRST line of the Convert method so all the other details are meaningless; my Convert method is not being called at all except when I add a "DataContext" to the image element. Please see me UPDATE to the question as this solution still doesn't work for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It never gets called because your property does not raise a `PropertyChanged` notification.  You need to either make it a `DependencyProperty` or implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise a `PropertyChanged` event when the property value is set.

Comment: Hi Ed. I have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged but still my Converter is not called. I used the debugger just to make sure that my implementation is correct and it seems to be right since when I assign to the property name I can confirm that a call of "NotifyPropertyChanged" with the name of the property take place.

Comment: Ed, I have modified the question to show my implementation of the solutions you have proposed. Thanks.

Comment: @MariusVE:  Ok.  Just for a quick sanity check, watch the output window when your control is created and when the property change should occur.  Do you see any binding errors appear?

Comment: Ed: I didn't see any binding errors showing up when the property change occured. Just for another sanity check, I have my breakpoint set at the very first line of the Convert method which is just the opening bracket (i.e., "{") so I'm positive it's not something stupid as missing a conditional or who knows what. I also confirmed that by hard coding an image path in the image element inside the xaml renders the image so it's not like it's invisible or anything like that.

Comment: Ed: I have edited the questions to show another attempt that I have made; it seems that this way my converter is being called... however, my setup is not correct.

Comment: Ed: Finally, I fixed the issue. The missing part of the puzzle was assigning the name of the class wrapping the property to the DataContext property of the image object defined in the XAML code. Thanks for your help.